# Find filter not working in Moongose on Referenced Entity

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two Entities, Organization and Applications. One organization can have many Applications.

```js
const organization = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Organization name is required.']
        }, // min 1 max 255
        // administrators get it from user table with org and role.
        applications: [
            // use populate in query
            {
                type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Application'
            }
        ]
```

I am trying to query Organization with two applications and its returning a blank array

```js
const organizations = await Organization.find({
                'applications': {
                    $all: [
                        '636bdf70bcd2d24005061023',
                        '6373ba91f53f95ca187809d6'
                    ]
                }
            }).populate('applications');
```

I tried running the same expression in MongoDB compass and it works. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your schema model, the `applications` field is an array of ObjectIDs, not an array of objects where each object would have `_id` property.

So instead of `applications._id`, it should be `applications`:

```js
const organizations = await Organization.find({
  applications: { 
    $all: ['636bdf70bcd2d24005061023', '6373ba91f53f95ca187809d6'] 
  }
})
.populate('applications');
```

Comment: I tried that and its not working.

Comment: Can you add example document from your db to the question?

Comment: I will get it. This query does work on MongoDB Compass.